# Open connection to site and parse the data

Tags: php, fsockopen

I want to build a script that open a connection to site and never closing.
the target is not to use every 5 secound on "file_get_contents".

I want once to open a socket and keep it live and parse there the data, so the other website server not see a new connection every 5 minutes.

The page I want to parse is a online currencies rates and updating live...

This is possible to do it via php?

Thanks!

Comment: It might be possible to keep the same connection open for a while, but the server would still see multiple requests as you would have to send a new request everytime you wanted the updated page, even if it is through the same socket.  PHP is also not really the correct language for this you need something more persistant.

Comment: ok but what is the best solution? ajax? please advice...

Comment: Hi John,  I am not sure i fully understand your requirement, but I have taken it as want to screen scrape a webpage updated by ajax in real time.  If I had this problem I would look at using an embedded browser control, for example a Windows application using the BrowserControl, you would then need this to run persitantly and output it's captured updates to a location (db or file) that can be read by your webpage via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible to my knowledge with php.

When the php page is displayed it is all static content.

The only way I know of to have `live update` is with ajax which with ping the other site multiple times.

Comment: you have some guide for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP socket_connect(), but it is almost certain that the server will close the connection after a while.